# Difference between <attr> and <dfn>

Tags: html

What is the semantic difference between

```html
<abbr title="Hubble Space Telescope">HST</abbr>
```

and

```html
<dfn title="Hubble Space Telescope">HST</dfn>
```

and

```html
<dfn><abbr title="Hubble Space Telescope">HST</abbr></dfn>
```

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn#Using_abbreviations_and_definitions_together) tries to explain, but it isn't very clear.

All three are valid markup (the third being explicitly listed in the linked example), so they presumably have different semantic meanings.  What are they?

Comment: Not sure what's unclear about the Mozilla documentation. It provides two examples, one where the surrounding paragraph _defines_ what the HST is, and so uses `<dfn>` and one where the surrounding paragraph just provides incidental information about the HST, and therefore doesn't.

Comment: It provides several examples, and I understand the logic for how it decides what the `<dfn>` tag refers to.  However, it doesn't really explain the *semantic* difference between the three examples I've given, above, just how they should be interpreted.  Or if it does, it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: To better understand the semantic meaning of your examples you must look at `dfn`'s usage in the context of its ancestor only.**

A common comprehension issue individuals face when dealing with semantics markup is to forget that the underlying intent is to come up with a [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) that would be understood by a large variety of artificial intelligences, accessability systems, lurkers, etc.

Someone asking Google/Siri/Cortana "*What does HST **stand for**?*", or "***What is** the Hubble Space Telescope?*" will be glad you used the appropriate combination of `dfn` and `abbr` to get a valuable answer.

> The **`dfn`** element represents the terms being defined within it's ancestor (`p`, `dt`, `dd`, or `section`)

```
<p>A <dfn>telescope</dfn> is an optical instrument meant to observe distant object.</p>
```

[The dfn Element. Mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn)

> The **`abbr`** element represents an abreviation, not necessarly being defined.

```
<p>The <abbr>HST</abbr> is named after astronomer Edwin Hubble.</p>

<p>The <abbr title="Hubble Space Telescope">HST</abbr> is named after astronomer Edwin Hubble.</p>
```

[The abbr Element. Mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr)

> The **`abbr`** and **`dfn`** elements combined may represents an abreviation, being defined within it's ancestor (`p`, `dt`, `dd`, or `section`).

```
<p>The <dfn><abbr title="Hubble Space Telescope">HST</abbr></dfn> is a space telescope launched into low Earth orbit in 1990.</p>
```

---

I hope this helps; don't hesitate if you have further questions!

Comment: That seems clear: The `<abbr>` tag is markup that says that the contents of the tag is an abbreviation.  Full stop.  The `<dfn>` tag is markup that says that the contents of the tag is a term that is being defined, AND the definition for that term is the parent element in which the term sits.  If the term being defined is also an abbreviation, then you would use both tags.  Good answer.

Comment: Having said that, it doesn't actually solve the problem that caused me to write this question (though it answers the question brilliantly!). We have code which highlights glossary terms when they appear in text and I was trying to work out what the best semantic markup would be. They are not necessarily abbreviations, so `<abbr>` is out, but also the definition of the term is not held within the parent element. I'm wondering whether we should just be using `<span>` with a title attribute (where the contents is the glossary term and the title is the def). However, this is not very semantic!

Comment: I'm not seeing the full picture here, and am making a few guesses, but it does sound like this last format would indeed be semantic. Remember `span` doesn't hold any semantic meaning. Therefore the following would be semantically correct: `<p><dfn class="formattedInItsOwnWay">Telescope</dfn><span class="formattedDiferently">An optical instrument meant to observe distant object.</span></p>`

Comment: A good example would be `<p>This list is sorted by <span title="This is the date the client was accepted onto the service.">engagement date</span>.</p>`, where `engagement date` is the term and `This is the date...` is the definition of that term.  The containing paragraph is not a definition of the term and may contain several terms, which rules out `<dfn>` being used in this context and the term is not an abbreviation, so `<abbr>` is also inappropriate (but *could* be used in situations where the term also happens to be an abbreviation, if that is known).

Answer (score -2):

the  tag is used, you should always use the title attribute, which indicates the meaning of the abbreviation or acronym.

```
abbr { 
  display: inline;
}
```

If you are using an unfamiliar or unusual abbreviation, you may want to consider also including a `<dfn>` element so provide additional information about the word or phrase.

```
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure this quite answers the question, i.e. what the semantic difference is between the examples.  My question is not related to appearance/styling.